# How do i stop a thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading, netbeans

I create a thread in Java inside a button to print a simple message but I cannot stop it.

```
Thread a = new Thread();
a.start();

while(true){
    try{
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("code");
    }catch(Exception e){
    }
}
```

when I click on it, itvstarts to print the code, but it seems to be blocked (the button). I would like to know. how can I stop the thread? And if I stop it, would be the button available again?.

I´m using netbeans 7.3, thanks.

Comment: Google Search is your better friend!

Comment: May be if you give to the program execution *a break*, then the button will be available to be pressed again...

Comment: @AndrewMao - starting a new thread does not block the thread that called `start()`. On the other hand, that `while(true)` loop will.

Comment: Google search often leads to SO.

Answer (score 1):

```
while(true){
}
```

starts an infinite loop due to which all the other operations are blocked.

Remove that

Answer (score 0):

The thread you are starting is not doing anything. It starts when you call `a.start()` and instantly terminates, because there is no code for this thread to run. Following this, the same thread that started the new one, and that is processing the click event, enters an infinite loop, so your user interface is completely blocked.

You need to give some code for the new thread to execute. To do so, you either pass the thread a `Runnable` or you override the thread's `run()` method. For example, to give it a `Runnable` containing the loop that prints every 2 seconds, you could do:

```
final Thread a = new Thread(new Runnable() {
  @Override public void run() {
    while (true) {
      try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("code");
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
};
a.start();
```

After that, if you ever want to stop that thread, you'd need to save a reference to the thread `a` in a field or something, and then call `a.interrupt()`. This will cause `sleep` to throw an `InterruptedException`, which will be caught and will execute `break`, which terminates the infinite loop and allows the thread to reach the end of the `run` method, which terminates the thread.

For example:

```
private Thread a = null;
... click handler on start button ... {
  if (a == null) {
    a = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        while (true) {
          try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.println("code");
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    };
    a.start();
  }
}

... click handler on "stop" button ... {
  if (a != null) {
    a.interrupt();
    a = null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not *stop* a thread in Java, you send an [`interrupt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29) signal.

The Thread may, or may no catch the signal. If it is `waiting`, or `sleeping` or `joining` ([`wait()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28long%29), [sleep()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) or join()) has been called on it), an [`InterruptedException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html) will be raised.

The Thread (in its while loop) can test whether it has been interrupted by calling the [`isInterrupted()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted%28%29) method and then decide to commit suicide (e.g. exit the loop).

Answer (score 0):

Use [interrupt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html). Then handle the `InterruptedException`